# Ubuntu 18.04 installer not able to set up LVM

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, 18.04, lvm

I'm in the process of setting up a new Ubuntu 18.04. But when I come to step 6/9 in the installer - Filesystem setup - it seems like there are several options missing, such as the options to set up LVM and Raid. When I go to manual setup I cannot find any options related to LVM (or Raid - not that I'm going to set that up now).

When creating a new partition, I only get this formats to choose from:
- ext4
- xfs
- btrfs
- swap
- leave unmounted

I was expecting to be able to set up LVM at this stage. Is there something I've missed, such as discontinued support for LVM and Raid, which I find highly unlikely, or do I need another installer? The one I'm trying is Ubuntu-18.04-live-server-amd64.iso.

//OJ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want all the available options to customize disk partitions, raid, etc, you should install Ubuntu using the **Network Installer**.

You can download it from [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads).

You need an active internet connection for this to work. When the installer reaches the point where it asks you what desktop to install, mark **Ubuntu Desktop** and select **Continue** if you want to install the normal desktop. Of course, you can mark any other Ubuntu flavor on that same menu and install that one if you like. (*Xubuntu Desktop, Kubuntu Desktop, Lubuntu Desktop, etc*)

Comment: Thank you Stormlord. This is exactly what I was after! Have a great day, good sir!

Comment: I really don't understand why support of LVM and RAID doesen't come with the standard 18.04 installation image.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install Ubuntu-Mate 18.04.2 desktop with LVM after several tries.  I tried as much as possible in the GUI.

- start Ubuntu-Mate as live desktop.
- install Synaptic package Manager
- install lvm2 and partitionmanager (gparted is not good enough for lvm handling)
- type in terminal: "sudo partionmanager"
  This should start the partionmanager as root.

In partionmanager do the following:

- create root partition (eg ext4)
- create swap
- in tools --> create new volume group, select partitions or drives to be part of the group
- apply
- select created volume group, create new partition (eg ext4) in the volume group, edit mount point (eg /home)
- apply

Now, start the installation of Ubuntu.  In the step where you are at filesystem setup: choose the last option: something else.  Now you should see the created root, swap and LVM/home partitions.  Select them with the same options as above (mount point root, swap and /home) and install.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run ubuntu without installing it and partition the way You like also with lvm. Then run the installer and choose lvm volumes to install to it. But You should be aware, that lvm setup on ubutu 18.04 might slow down your boot time significantly. You should not split usr and root partition on systemd managed os.